# React with Materialize css select box, focus method issue

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Please help

I'm using materialize version 1.0.0-rc.1 with react.
When I call javascript method to focus input field, it works only with textbox field.
You can check my code here at [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/minhna/full/JvmyqQ)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to call `focus()` method of the `input` element which is a property of the instance returned by init command `M.FormSelect.init()`.

```
const selectInstance = M.FormSelect.init(elm, {});
// then to focus the select field
selectInstance.input.focus();
```